# Suppose $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are topologies on $X$ defined by $d$ and $p $,respectively which of the following statement is True

Tags: general-topology

let $(\ X,d)$ be  a  metric space . consider the metric $ p$ on $X$ defined by $\ p(x,y) = min \{\frac{1}{2}, d(x,y) \}, x,y \in X$. Suppose $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are topologies on $X$ defined by  $d$ and $p  $,respectively

which of the  following statement is True ?

$a)$ $\tau_{1}$ is  a proper  subset of $\tau_{2}$

$b)$$\tau_{2}$ is  a proper  subset of $\tau_{1}$

$c)$ neither $\tau_{1} \subseteq  \tau_{2}$ nor $\tau_{2} \subseteq  \tau_{1}$

$d)$$\tau_{1} =\tau_2$

My attempts : i thinks option c ) will correct

is it true ?

Comment: Do you have a justification for your attempt?

Comment: @angryavian, open ball of radius  less then 1\2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is d).

Indeed, recall how you generate topology from a metric: $U$ is open if for any $x\in U$ there is $r>0$ such that an open ball $B(x,r)$ centered at $x$ of radius $r$ is fully contained in $U$. Or shortly: $B(x,r)\subseteq U$. Open ball in the given metric of course.

Now all you have to see is that for $0<r<\frac{1}{2}$ open balls in both metrics coincide.

Comment: thanks u @freakish